# Matlab column multiplication of a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, multiplication, vector-multiplication

How can I multiply columns of a matrix and obtain a column vector.

Example:
A =

```
 1     1     4
 3     2     2
 2     1     1
 4     1     1
```

Expected output:
C =

```
 4
12
 2
 4
```

Any ideas without for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use the inbuilt `prod` function as `prod(A,2)` or `prod(A')'`.

For example:

```
>> 
A = [
1     1     4
3     2     2
2     1     1
4     1     1
];
```

Now:

```
>> prod(A,2)

ans =

    4
    12
    2
    4
```

For more details, try `help prod`.

Comment: `prod` has a dimension option, that will allow a direct computation without the transpose.

Answer (score 2):

Once again, google and the Matlab documentation are your friend.
You are looking for the function [`prod`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/prod.html):

```
prod(A,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple loop could do this for you too if you don't know the size of the matrix in hand. Just build a new vector by row-wise multiplication of elements in A.